# Passing values into CASE statement

Tags: database

and thank you all in advance for your help.

I'm trying to take the results from two separate queries and include them in a third query that has a CASE statement. I've had some success but I'm not able to present the results of the third query in the proper order. The purpose of this is to show the employee count for each department under the different managers. So far I can only load separately the manager names and their departments and employee department count totals by department. What I can't figure out is how to get the manager names in and the employee department count in for each manager row. Below are the two source queries I've used so far and the query with the CASE statement. I've also looked at UNPIVOT function with no success yet.

a) This simple query lists each primary manager name. There are also sub managers that will be returned using a hierarchy query later.

```
select name from employees "Boss" where employeeid in 
(‘1’,'5','25','84','85');
```

b) This query returns the department id count for each main manager  (‘1’,'5','25','84','85') as well as all sub-managers.

```
select departmentid, count(departmentid) COUNT from employees
where departmentid = departmentid and level <= 3
connect by prior employeeid = bossid        
start with employeeid = 5
group by departmentid
order by departmentid;
```

c) Here’s a CASE statement that outputs exactly as desired. The problem here is the select statement currently outputs only the manager names and the manager departments into the columns. What I need to do is output both the manager names and the manager's employee department counts into the individual manager row columns. I've tried to do a separate select of the manager names to get the ‘Boss’ column and another select to include the department counts. But that got messy. Also passing the counts in a second statement would create an additional unwanted column.

```
select e.name "Boss",
COUNT(CASE WHEN d.departmentid = '1' THEN 1 END) AS "Finance",
COUNT(CASE WHEN d.departmentid = '2' THEN 1 END) AS "HR",
COUNT(CASE WHEN d.departmentid = '3' THEN 1 END) AS "IT",
COUNT(CASE WHEN d.departmentid = '4' THEN 1 END) AS "Marketing",
COUNT(CASE WHEN d.departmentid = '5' THEN 1 END) AS "Sales"
from employees e, departments d
where e.employeeid in (select distinct e.bossid from employees e)
and e.departmentid = d.departmentid (+)
group by e.name
order by e.name;
```

Boss                        Finance         HR         IT          Marketing      Sales
--------------------        ----------         ----------   ---------- ----------          ----------
Baxter Carney                 0                    0          0              0                 1
Blythe Pierce                   0                    0          0               0                1

Here's an altered CASE query that loads the employee department counts but unfortunately it loads by department and not by individual manager. That is the problem I'm stuck on right now. How to pass the counts to the right manager and into the right column.

```
select departmentid "DEPTNO",
COUNT(CASE WHEN departmentid = '1' THEN 1 END) AS "Finance",
COUNT(CASE WHEN departmentid = '2' THEN 1 END) AS "HR",
COUNT(CASE WHEN departmentid = '3' THEN 1 END) AS "IT",
COUNT(CASE WHEN departmentid = '4' THEN 1 END) AS "Marketing",
COUNT(CASE WHEN departmentid = '5' THEN 1 END) AS "Sales"
from employees
where departmentid = departmentid and level <= 3
connect by prior employeeid = bossid
start with employeeid = 5
group by departmentid
order by departmentid
```

/

```
DEPTNO    Finance         HR         IT  Marketing      Sales
```

---

```
     3          0          0          1          0          0               
     5          0          0          0          0         21
```

And here's for all managers. You can see that it just keeps increasing the individual department count.

```
DEPTNO    Finance         HR         IT  Marketing      Sales
```

---

```
     1          4          0          0          0          0               
     2          0         23          0          0          0               
     3          0          0         20          0          0               
     4          0          0          0          1          0               
     5          0          0          0          0         28
```